# Recommendation for cutting corner of tile?

Tags: electrical, tile

I need to take out about a half inch from the top right of the tile in the bottom left of the opening for this outlet.

I’m upgrading it from an old outlet to a gfci outlet and it needs a bit more clearance.

Would the dremel tile cutting attachment be the best bet or should I use a type of grinder?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

[image: tile picture]

Comment: I'd use the dremel tile cutting attachment. Smaller and easier to control then a angle grinder. If you have tile snips, you may be able to snip pieces off

Comment: Thanks @MicahMontoya, ended up doing that and worked great. If you'd like to add this as an answer I'd be glad to accept it to give you proper credit.

Answer (score 1):

Score it to half depth with an angle grinder to make the corner.  Note that you do not need to score it so the two lines meet as this might bleed over.   Tap with hammer.

If no angle grinder you can use a sharp chisel and basically scratch through it with about the same method.   The cut does have to be perfect since you will have a plate over it, although you do not want too much coming out.

Answer (score 1):

Vibratory tile cutters are wonderful tools for just this sort of application. I might still be tempted to use the dremel cutoff grinder disc. Its slow but reliable. Great for scoring if you are starting a job for the vibratory cutter that is hard to start. 
You can get a vibratory cutter for $30. Practice on ceramic tile if thats what you want to cut. I use mine on wood too. . . But you need ventilation for deeper cuts in wood. . since the blade will smoke. With the right tool head.. a vibratory cutter can cut metal wood ceramic or butter. I mean polymer. Getting a cut started may require patience and some practice.

My introduction to a vibratory cutter was the same application as yours. An electrical contractor was putting in extra outlets in my kitchen. And had to trim some tiles. He pulled out an expensive name brand vibratory cutter and made quick work of it. I tried the cheapy version later and it works.. just not on lots of heavy or very precise cutting.

Comment: I think the these are also called oscillating tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tile nipper to take out most of it, and to get a clean edge, use a diamond grip tile file.  Using a grinder will be faster, but your place will be very dusty.